# how to retrieve a list using like statement in JDBCTemplate ?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I try to return a list of data with an entered word, but it returns null

```
    public List<people> peoples(String l) {

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    try {
        String sql = "select * from people where peopleName like '?' ;";
        List<people> peoples = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{"%"+l+"%"},
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(people.class));
        return peoples;

    } catch (DataAccessException e) {

    }catch(NullPointerException nullPointer) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: whats the error you're getting?

Comment: you get null due to there is some exception , buy you hide it and see nothing in console / log.  you have two catch blocks and they are empty . add printStacktrace() and you will see why you get null

Comment: @avisheks it doesn't show any error just it returns null

Comment: @sbjavateam ok ill try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`select * from people where peopleName like ?`

instead of

`select * from people where peopleName like '?'`

Don't use the " ' "  value before and after placeholder value ? . It always searches the  peoplename like ? not with your value

Answer (score 0):

please check if data source is instantiated correctely.